# Sphinx not search for English word with underscore in Japanese document

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

I created Japanese and English documents in sphinx, which had the same contents. Japanese document includes some English words.
If you search for an English word with an underline in both documents (for example,
"OMP_NUM_THREADS"), you will see the search results in English, but not in Japanese.

Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Please provide sample RST documents as well as other information needed to reproduce the problem (see [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I created following two minimal pages. 
This page has only a single word "OMP_NUM_THREADS".
(Please see http://omni-compiler.org/~mnakao/en/_sources/index.rst.txt)

https://omni-compiler.org/~mnakao/en/
https://omni-compiler.org/~mnakao/ja/

When you search OMP_NUM_THREADS in Japanese page, the word is not found.

Comment: I see. Searching for `OMP_NUM_THREADS` does not work here: https://omni-compiler.org/~mnakao/ja/. It does work here: https://omni-compiler.org/~mnakao/en/.